# Reverse int array but only half done in result

Tags: java, arrays

i use this to reverse an int array,

```
int[] a = new int[10];
    System.out.print("a[i]: ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        a[i] = i + 1;
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("a[i] reverse: ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length/2 ; i++) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[a.length-i-1];
            a[a.length-i-1] = temp;
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
```

the result is like this:

```
a[i]: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
a[i] reverse: 10 9 8 7 6
```

Whats wrong in the code? why half of the array in the reversed version is gone?
Thank you

Comment: You are only printing half the array in your second loop.

Comment: Thats the problem: `a.length/2`. You are iterating over the half array only, like Eran commented secods earlier :-)

Comment: for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length/2 ; i++) { -- Due to this your code only print half of the array.

Comment: i was so blind haha, why i didnt see it.....i put the print inside the for loop, thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

Print the array `a` after you're done with *reversing* like below:

```
//reverse it
System.out.print("a[i] reverse: ");
for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = temp;
}

//now print it
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

which

**outputs**:

```
a[i]: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
a[i] reverse: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length/2 ; i++)` is wrong. loop state count is  half of array size. So that you print half of array. You must write

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by replacing your code

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length/2 ; i++) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[a.length-i-1];
        a[a.length-i-1] = temp;
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
```

with..

```
System.out.println(a.length);
    for(int i=a.length;i>0;i--){
         System.out.print(a[i-1]+" ");
    }
```